# jQuery UI Droppable - blocking overlay areas

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a fairly tricky layout using jqueryui draggable/droppable.

In one section, there is a droppable area inside of a div container.  The container has overflow:hidden, but the contained droppable exceeds the bounds of the container.

In concrete terms, say I have a 200px tall droppable contained in a 100px tall div w/ overflow: hidden.

The problem:  When dragging a draggable element, it considers the whole 200px droppable area as droppable, even though only 100px is exposed through the container.

How can I get draggable/droppale to only respect the visible area of the droppable?

NOTE: This design is a part of a larger complex interface containing many droppables, and there are valid reasons for this setup.  Solutions of "change your markup" will not be considered.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xS7S9/)

You can make the child droppable element resize to the parent's height and width whenever the parent resizes. After you setup that listener, just trigger the parent resize event and the droppable container will always match the width & height of the parent.

```
$("#drop-container").resize(function(){
    $(this).find('#drop-content').width($(this).width());
    $(this).find('#drop-content').height($(this).height());
});
$("#drop-container").trigger('resize');
$("#drop-content").droppable({
    accept: '.special', 
    hoverClass: 'dropme'
});

$(".special").draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that also works when you have a table as content, but uses a global variable:

[Sample when content is table](http://jsfiddle.net/SilenoRocco/y5ajqq0w/)

```
var DIV_AREA_OVER = false;

$("#drop-container").resizable();
$("#drop-container").droppable({ 
    hoverClass: 'dropme',
    over: function() { DIV_AREA_OVER = true; },
    out: function() { DIV_AREA_OVER = false; }
});
$("#table-content td").droppable({ 
    hoverClass: 'dropme',
    drop: function() {
        var wrap = $(this).closest('#drop-container');
        if (DIV_AREA_OVER == true) {
            $(this).addClass("accepted");
        }
    }
});
$(".special").draggable({
    start: function() { DIV_AREA_OVER = false; },
    stop: function() { DIV_AREA_OVER = false; }
});
```